# does the compiler assume that private const members *never* change?

Tags: c++, optimization, constants, volatile

```
class A{
    const size_t number;
public:
    A(size_t number): number(number) {}
    void f(){
        //read number, possibly save in CPU register
        //call a function that the compiler can't inspect
        //    so it should assume that anything in the program state changed
        //read number again
    }
```

There, where it reads the `number` again, will the compiler (if optimization is on) still assume that it cannot have changed, because it's `const`, and so read the flag from the CPU register, if it was placed in one of them before?

Comment: If you want to know if the compiler *can* do that, the answer is yes. If you want to know if the compiler *will* do that, you need to see for yourself.

Comment: Typecasting can break all rules.

Comment: @Jaywalker Doesn’t matter. Such a typecast would be UB and the compilers don’t have to pay any heed to UB code.

Comment: Even if it wasn't `const` a compiler could legitimately choose to keep it around in a register instead for a while if it can prove there's no aliasing and keep the observable behaviour correct (and prior to C++11 the standard said nothing about threads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that It depends on the implementation detail of the particular compiler.
Primary purpose of const correctness is to prevent yourself from making honest mistakes and writing more intuitive code which is easy to maintain.
Compiler optimization should (*almost*)never be a criteria for making something `const`.

A good compiler might apply its optimizations and inline the `const` variable, others may not.
Some factors like if the address of the `const` variable is taken somewhere might also effect the way in how the compiler handles it.

Last and most important regardless of how the compiler handles it once you declare a variable `const`, your code should ***always*** assume that it is const, it should never be modified, modifying it with any hackery will cause an Undefined Behavior.